# R/Open air Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : 'to' must be a finite number

Tags: r, openair

I am trying to use the function "Summaryplot" from the Openair Package in R. But everytime I tried to use it with the next data matrix, you only have to use the next code to extract the info:

```
structure(list(Fecha = structure(c(1577840400, 1577844000, 1577847600, 
1577851200, 1577854800, 1577858400, 1577862000, 1577865600, 1577869200, 
1577872800, 1577876400, 1577880000, 1577883600, 1577887200, 1577890800, 
1577894400, 1577898000, 1577901600, 1577905200, 1577908800, 1577912400, 
1577916000, 1577919600, 1577923200, 1577926800), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), PM10_CDAR = c(11.4, 8.3, 13.3, 16, 
39.5, 35.4, 31, 48.7, 41, 34, 23.3, 16.5, 21.8, 15.7, 17.8, 12.7, 
12.8, 16, 11.3, 7.9, 8.1, 10, 10.4, 7.7, 6.1), PM10_KEN = c(49.7, 
72.4, 34.5, 50.3, 65.2, 59, 25.5, 19.6, 17.4, 14.3, 48.2, 34.8, 
25.3, 56.7, 26, 45.6, 29, 30.5, 24.1, 22, 26.9, 22.2, 17.3, 19.1, 
15.5), PM10_LAF = c(28.8, 69, 72.3, 35.1, 82, 44, 69, 73, 46, 
43, 29.9, 25.1, 21.4, 15.8, 11.7, 16, 15, 12, 9, 10.8, 10.1, 
11.9, 12.9, 12.4, 11.8), PM10_TUN = c(45, 57, 93, 69, 73, 60, 
45, 69, 61, 46, 28, 20, 33, 54, 44, 27, 39, 37, 36, 41, 30, 29, 
18, 4, 7), PM2.5_CDAR = c(9, 8, 10, 16, 34, 30, 33, 42, 33, 34, 
6, 10, 9, 9, 15, 10, 9, 7, 9, 5, 5, 10, 6, 4, 2), PM2.5_KEN = c(49, 
81, 110, 83, 63, 59, 79, 68, 84, 76, 48, 19, 22, 34, 36, 33, 
29, 19, 13, 22, 3, 16, 16, 6, 9), PM2.5_LAF = c(35, 65, 53, 30, 
60, 62, 64, 67, 36, 43, 21, 16, 11, 11, 10, 15, 15, 12, 9, 6, 
6, 10, 10, 9, 10), PM2.5_TUN = c(39, 42, 66, 54, 52, 39, 33, 
40, 42, 33, 21, 11, 13, 27, 22, 17, 21, 15, 17, 15, 13, 10, 6, 
4, 2)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-25L))
```

the next error appears:

```
> summaryPlot(date.zoo_2, pollutant = "Kennedy_PM10")
Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : 'to' must be a finite number
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min.default(numeric(0), na.rm = TRUE) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max.default(numeric(0), na.rm = TRUE) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

I tried everything, to change the date column into date as. `idx <- as.POSIXct(datos_meterologicos$Fecha)`; `datos_meterologicos$Fecha <- read.zoo(datos_meterologicos, FUN=as.POSIXct, format = "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M", tz="UTC")`. And frankly, I don´t know what to do because the same error is still appearing.
The whole code is next

```
date.matrix_2 <- as.data.frame(datos_meterologicos[,-1])
idx_2 <- as.POSIXct(datos_meterologicos$Fecha)
date.xts_2 <- as.xts(date.matrix_2,order.by=idx_2)
date.zoo_2 <- as.zoo(date.xts_2)
```

Comment: Greetings! I realize you have shared a spreadsheet of your data, but usually it is more helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Comment: Ok, thank you for the information. I already put the data with the dput function. I hope to get a more suitable data.